# Create table based on max value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a `PostgreSQL` database with data from car tracking which looks similar to this.

```
+--------+-------+---------+------------+
| car_id | trip  |  speed  |  Segment   |
+--------+-------+---------+------------+
|    1   |   1   |    82   |     s1     |
|    1   |   1   |    81   |            |
|    1   |   1   |    85   |     s1     |
|    1   |   2   |    82   |     s1     |
|    1   |   2   |    76   |     s2     |
|    2   |   3   |    80   |     s1     |
|    2   |   3   |    84   |     s2     |
|    2   |   3   |    83   |     s2     |
+--------+-------+---------+------------+
```

Where every car has a specific `car_id`, and the `trip` changes based on that `car_id` or a change in date-time bigger than 5 sec. For every data point the `speed` is registered, and what part of the road the track belongs to (`segment`).

I would like to end up with a table where the maximum `speed` is shown, for each `trip` for each `segment`. If possible the `car_id` should be shown as well. It should look like this:

```
+-------+----------+------+------+
| trip  |  car_id  |  s1  |  s2  |
+-------+----------+------+------+
|   1   |  1       |  85  |      |
|   2   |  1       |  82  |  76  |
|   3   |  2       |  80  |  84  |
+-------+----------+------+------+
```

I have tried to use a `group by` but I can't make it work. I will be grateful if anyone can help.

Comment: "Change in datetime bigger than 5 sec".  There is no "datetime" column.  And why isn't "s1" shown for trip 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just conditional aggregation:

```
select trip_id, car_id,
       max(speed) filter (where segment = 's1') as s1,
       max(speed) filter (where segment = 's2') as s2
from t
group by trip_id, car_id
```